# Create Flask application to run Python program in backend and display terminal output to webpage on /logging url

Tags: python-3.x, flask, terraform, frontend, backend

I m bit new to frontend using python. Need help to design the frontend which can fulfill below requirements:

1. Take User Inputs for few variables.
2. Pass those variables tocall a function inside a python program( another file written in python and imported as module in flask app ( for example)).
3. while it execute that function in background . all terminal output that it generate when you run python program manually  either should be saved in a file as log or stream directly those terminal output displayed on an  webpage under /logging url path.

**Here is my backend code**

````
    import os
    import shutil
    user_input={}
    ################################ input variable generation  for cli pupose only #################
    #def numericvalue(a,b):
    #  user_input[a]=int(b)
    #  return
    #def alphavalue(a,b):
    #  user_input[a]=b
    #  return
    #template_variables=
    #["empid","last_name","natnw","vmimagesourcepath","worker_count","worker_vcpu","worker_memory","master_vcpu","master_memory"]
    #for i in template_variables:
    #  temp_value=input(i+":")
    #  if temp_value.isalnum():
    #    alphavalue(i,temp_value)
    #  elif temp_value.isnumeric() :
    #    numericvalue(i,temp_value)
    #  else:
    #    alphavalue(i,temp_value)
    #####################################function will be called from frontend ( if created) ########
    def infra_create(a,b,c,d,e,f,g):
    
      user_input["empid"]=int(a)
      user_input["last_name"]=b
      user_input["worker_vcpu"]=int(c)
      user_input["worker_count"]=int(d)
      user_input["worker_memory"]=int(e)
      user_input["master_vcpu"]=int(f)
      user_input["master_memory"]=int(g)
    #################### create directory for user ###################
      print("creating directory for",user_input["last_name"])
      path = os.path.join("/root/", user_input["last_name"])
    
    ######################## user input and templating section ##############################
      os.system('rm -f /root/infra_templates_gen/user_input.yml')
      os.system('echo "---\nvar: var">/root/infra_templates_gen/user_input.yml')
      f = open("/root/infra_templates_gen/user_input.yml", "a")
      for key,value in user_input.items():
        f.writelines("\n"+key+": "+value)
      f.close()
      print("generating tf from template")
      os.system('/usr/bin/ansible-playbook'+" "+path+"/templategen.yml" )
      print("copying relevantfiles to ", path)
      shutil.copytree(os.getcwd(),path)
      print("copied")
    
    ###################### generate tf from Tf template using variable file and ansible
    ############################# running terraform init ######################
      init_command="terraform -chdir="+path+" "+"init"
      os.system(init_command)
      plan_command="terraform -chdir="+path+" "+"plan"
      os.system(plan_command)
      print("---------------------------------------Plan execution ends here ---------------------------")
    #apply_signal=input("Do you wish to run terraform apply?")
    #if apply_signal.lower() =='y' or apply_signal.lower()=='yes':
    #
    #  os.system('terraform apply')
    #else:
    #  print("Exiting from Program")
      return  ```

**Here is frontend code i tried using flask** .
```  import logging

    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    import userinput
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug') # grabs underlying WSGI logger
    handler = logging.FileHandler('test.log') # creates handler for the log file
    logger.addHandler(handler) # adds handler to the werkzeug WSGI logger
    
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('test.html')
    
    #@app.route('/k8sclustercreate', methods=['POST'])
    def hello():
        logger.info("Here's some info")
        empid = request.form['empid']
        last_name = request.form['last_name']
        worker_vcpu = request.form['worker_vcpu']
        worker_count = request.form['worker_count']
        worker_memmory = request.form['worker_memory']
        master_vcpu = request.form['master_vcpu']
        master_memory = request.form['master_memory']
        return 
 userinput.infra_create(empid,last_name,worker_vcpu,worker_count,worker_memory,master_vcpu,master_memory)

############ this is i m trying to achieve but no success ############

    @app.route('/logging', methods=["GET"])
    def stream():
        """returns logging information"""
        return Response(hello(), mimetype="text/plain", content_type="text/event-stream")
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3000) ```

**HTML file Test**
````

Kubernetes Cluster Create

#### Kubernetes Cluster Create webpage

### Enter following details , Leave blank for default values

Here  we need to provide some info to initiate terraform plan
            
                Emp ID: 
                Last Name: 
                Worker Count:
                Worker vCPU: 
                Worker Memory(MB): 
                Master vCPU: 
                Master Memory(MB):

```
**HTML Logging (This is sample i im trying to achieve with logging**
```

Flask app with logging
  
  
    
      Logging will appear here:
      
        
      
    
  

```
**CSS FILE**
```
test.css
p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}
h2 {
    color: navy;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

custom.css
.logging_window{
display: block;
padding: 9.5px;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #333;
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
width: 50%;
margin: auto;
}

Comment: Try writing the command execution output to a file and read that file in the route `/logging`

Comment: I tried to redirect the out to logs.log while running cli but reading that file from flask route says internal server error